# Help understanding how to make a simple 3D minimum bounding sphere?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I need to develop a minimum bounding sphere. It'll only *ever* be in 3 dimensions, and the numbers of points are relatively small (500-5000 total). Performance is important however.

I was looking for some help finding/understanding an algorithm to do this.

Getting an exact answer would be preferred, but I think if the radius is ~3-5% larger that might still be doable.

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere) the most promising algorithms seemed to be the ones by Emo Welzl, Fischer or Larsson.

However, I'm not following how any of the algorithms actually...work.

[**Fischer's**](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/subdir/texts/own_work/seb.pdf) has an open-source implementation [here](https://github.com/hbf/miniball) but there's so much boilerplate, error-checking, generality, logging and fluff that I can't follow the *algorithm* part of it. (And using it as-is wouldn't work, I really need something much smaller and simpler that I can write myself) I couldn't follow the paper very well, but maybe it's much simpler than I realize.

[**Larsson's**](https://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/article.asp?issue=034&article=9) (Extremal Points Optimal Sphere) seems promising but the pseudo-code in [the paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4254/be8dfbb32e97661b55fd3a9b6743d3b88d69.pdf) seems to be leaving a lot out (FindExtremalPoints, MinimumSphere, GrowSphere, etc), and I'm confused what the array of N is for, among other things.

[**Emo Welzl's**](http://www.stsci.edu/~RAB/Backup%20Oct%2022%202011/f_3_CalculationForWFIRSTML/Bob1.pdf) is the one I think I understand the most but again the [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Bounding_volumes/classCGAL_1_1Min__sphere__of__spheres__d.html) isn't making any sense, that seems like it's just the entry point and not the actual code to create the sphere. B_MINIDISK I think is where the bulk work is being done in the paper, but it feels like there's a step missing or something is getting brushed over.

EDIT: Maybe MTFDISK and B_MTFDISK are actually what I need? I still don't follow what `b_md` is though, and it's said that it's "non-trivial".

Could anyone explain in simpler terms how one of these three works or suggest an alternative? I think partially because these are intended to work for many dimensions I've gotten very confused.

Comment: I think Welzl's algorithm is a good and simple approach in 3D, although the paper is a bit terse on some points. I will try explain it here when I have the time.

Comment: @Discretelizard Thank you, that would be a great help.

Comment: Well shoot! The other answer was deleted, and they left no message of any kind. They didn't leave any explanation. It seemed like it would work, too.

Comment: I've deleted my answer cause it doesn't look very different from the ancient algorithm of Jack Ritter, briefly described on Wiki page you already visited.

Comment: If my answer seems useful to you, I can undelete it

Comment: @HEKTO No, that's alright. Thank you. I'll look that one over.

Comment: The implementation of the Emo Welzl algorithm you referred to is a part of the CGAL library, so if you try to use it it will bring a lot into your project (I'm not saying it's a bad thing). However there exists a standalone implementation (header only, in C++) of his algorithm on his home page - please see: https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/subdir/software/miniball.html